Can the water heater and dryer share the same circuit and breaker
The dryer has a separate switch that turns on only dryer when in use.

What type of water heater is this? What is the circuit voltage and breaker current limit?

Why are you wanting this? There are likely better ways to get what you want here...

I agree this feels like an XY Problem and feel free to [edit] to provide your actual "view from 30,000 feet" goal.   However to be brief, there are load shed technologies that can pre-empt one to run the other. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zheQKmAT_a0 And this could be as simple as a sliding-plate "geneartor interlock" such as Siemens ECSPBK02 or Eaton CHML between the panel breakers. If it is a plain switch, it must be 2-pole because of the dryer.

The devil is in the details.
A circuit can only have general purpose receptacles if < 50% of the circuit capacity is hardwired loads.
A circuit can't have hardwired loads greater than 100% capacity (obviously) or 80% capacity for continuous loads due to the required derate.
In the US, a typical tank water heater will use between 19A (4500W) and 23A (5500W). A typical clothes dryer will use 23A. Both of these are sized to fit "just right" on a 30A circuit.
The only way to make this work is if a switch (which has to switch 2 hots instead of 1 and be rated for at least 30A) only allows one appliance or the other to receive power at any time. That is easy for 2 dishwashers (120V, so only 1 hot, standard 15A or 20A "3 way" switch), which my family had when I was a kid. It could work just as well for water heater and dyer but only with the right type of switch.

If you mean the "separate switch" changes the circuit from feeding only the water heater to feeding only the dryer, that works electrically, if both are rated for the same amperage.
